# How to return an array of in order traversal of the specified subtree (left subtree or right subtree of specified node)

Tags: java, binary-tree

I implement it using recursive function, as shown below. I am pretty sure I implement it in the right order, However I seem to fail the test cases of my assingment, can someone point out where went wrong in my code?

```
/**
 * Build an array of nodes in the specified subtree.
 *
 * @param node  the parent node, not to be included in returned array
 * @param child the specified subtree
 * @return array of nodes
 */
//countNodes return the total number of nodes in the subtree excluding the parent node

public TreeNode[] enumerateNodes(TreeNode node, Child child) {
    TreeNode[] treeNodes = new TreeNode[countNodes(node, child)];
    if(child == Child.RIGHT) {
        node = node.right;
    }
    if(child == Child.LEFT) {
        node = node.left;
    }
    enumerateNodes(node, treeNodes, 0);
    return treeNodes;
}
private void enumerateNodes(TreeNode node, TreeNode[] arrays, int cur){
    if(node == null){
        return;
    }
    enumerateNodes(node.left, arrays, cur);
    arrays[cur++] = node;
    enumerateNodes(node.right, arrays, cur);
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger and observe `cur` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H

/ --- \

L1  ----  R1

/ \ ------  /   \

L2

Sorry for the ugly tree, but look here when you go left you reach null ptr on left child of L1 being L2. You go up, call this:

```
arrays[cur++] = node;
```

Now cur got 0, the array will have L2 as the first node (index 0). Will increment to 1. Go right with the correct value. All good here so far.

However. When you exhaust the left subtree. You'll go to the right subtree (with head R).

```
array[0] = L1 // this will override L2
```

Comment: @FocDr if this solved your problem, please accept the answer. That way, StackOverflow users, who check your question in the future will benefit from it.